# RPC Server is unavailable Exception during SetPassword in Active Directory

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I am trying to create user in Active Directory from my C# Windows Application. The users are getting created but when I try to set the password for that user I receive an exception "RPC server is unavailable". I spoke to the windows teams and as per them the RPC service is up and running on the AD server. Please advice

Below is my code:

```
using (var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://testldap.test.com:389/OU=Users,OU=My Project,DC=test,DC=com", "adminUser", "adminPass", AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind))
               {
                   using (var newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=dummy1", "user"))
                   {
                       newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = "dummy1";
                       newUser.CommitChanges();
                   }
               }

               using (var user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://testldap.test.com:389/CN=dummy1,OU=Users,OU=My Project,DC=test,DC=com", "adminUser", "adminPass"))
               {
                   user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "ComplexString@321" });
                   user.CommitChanges();
               }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954819/trying-to-create-a-new-active-directory-user-invokesetpassword-pwd-throws

Comment: Also, if you can, it might be a good idea to try the newer c# library `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` instead of "raw" LDAP.

Comment: I tried with ```System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement``` but still same issue